# Recursively count a number of vowels in a string (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, recursion

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong in my code?
I need to count the number of vowel occurances in a string using recursion. The function isVowels checks if the character is a vowel and it works. But this code below doesn't work...

```
function countVowels(str) {
    var length = str.length;
    if (length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (isVowel(str.charAt(length)) == false) {
        return countVowels(str.substring(0, length - 1));
    }
    return 1 + countVowels(str.substring(0, length - 1));
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean in this case? Do you get the wrong result? Do you get an error?

Comment: For all the different cases I get a 0 as a result

Comment: that's because you'll end up with a length of 0 at the end of your recursion.

Comment: What are the cases? Please provide a **complete** example (i.e. runnable code) and update your question with a proper description of the problem.

Comment: @BelgianMyWaffle: That's the base case. Why should that be a problem?

Comment: So for a string "abcd" it returns 0, for a string "b" it returns 0, for "aaa" it returns 0.

Comment: `str.charAt(length)`, shouldn't this be `str.charAt(length - 1)`?

Comment: Consider a simple regular expression. It's less efficient, but a *tiny* fraction of the code: `"this is a test".match(/[aeiou]/ig).length`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Characters in a string are - just like elements in an array - [zero-indexed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering). You will need to use `.charAt(length-1)`, or you're getting the character after the end of the string (which yields the empty string). This should do it:

```
function countVowels(str) {
    var length = str.length;
    if (length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (isVowel(str.charAt(length - 1)) == false) {
        return countVowels(str.substring(0, length - 1));
    }
    return 1 + countVowels(str.substring(0, length - 1));
}
```

However, you could simplify this by not calling the recursive part twice, and counting from the front:

```
function countVowels(str) {
    if (str.length == 0)
        return 0;
    return (isVowel(str.charAt(0)) ? 1 : 0) + countVowels(str.slice(1));
}
```